# Formtastic Unable to find input class for date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime, datepicker, mongoid

I'm creating a very basic form with formtastic and mongoid as ORM.
Now I first tried to set the type of my field manually but I got the same error.
Now I also applied this ['patch'](https://gist.github.com/3742676) so the field types are automatically mapped like with ActiveRecord but I still getting the same issue:

```
Unable to find input class for date_select
```

or

```
Unable to find input class for datetime_select
```

This is my model

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document

  paginates_per 25

  field :title, type: String
  field :date,  type: Date
  field :place, type: String
end
```

So this is very basic. 
I'm using ruby-1.9.3-p194, formtastic (2.2.1) and mongoid (3.0.13) but I don't think this issue is mongo related. I suspect formtastic is the problem over here. Does anybody experienced the same problem? 
Any tips are very welcome!

Comment: Just had the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Having this issue as well, very odd that this wouldn't be found automatically.